# Appreciate help with solving a probability density function for its constant term

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, probability-distributions

I am using StackOverflow a lot for asking and answering programming related questions, and I hope it is appropriate if I'd ask my question below on here on this sister-site. If not, please let me know and I will delete it.

So, my problem is that my highschool and college math skill math skills are a little bit rusty. I am about to get the equation to determine the constant term in a probability density function. However, I am not even sure if mine is the right approach. And even if it is, I am really concerned that I made a big and stupid mistake in my equations here.

I hope you have one or the other good tip for me that can help me on my way to get the correct solution.

Thank you!

I thought it might be best if I post an image of what I have done so far. So what I want is to solve "T" here.

[image]

## EDIT

Thanks for your answer, I think I am getting closer to understanding the solution. However, I am a little bit confused how you got the "2zT" onto the right side of the equation. Because it is a probability density function, I assumed that the area below the integral would be =1.

So where I am stuck right now is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not quite right.  I assume that $y, z$ are fixed real parameters with $z > 0$, and that the density function has support $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$.  In such a case, we write $$u = (x-y)/z, \quad du = \frac{1}{z} \, dx.$$  Then the integral becomes $$\begin{align*} z T \int_{u = -\infty}^\infty e^{-|u|} \, du &= 2z T \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-u} \, du \\ &= 2z T \left[ -e^{-u} \right]_{u=0}^\infty  \\ &= 2z T (0 - (-e^0)) = 2z T. \end{align*}$$  In the first step, we exploit symmetry:  since $\left|-u\right| = |u|$, the integral over $u \in (-\infty, \infty)$ is equal to twice the integral over $u \in [0,\infty)$.  In order to obtain a probability density, the integral of the density over its support must equal $1$; thus, $T = \frac{1}{2z}$.  Note that this value depends only on the scale parameter $z$, not the location parameter $y$, which makes sense:  moving the distribution's center will not affect its area when the support is infinite, but scaling it will affect the area.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to point me to the right solution. Unfortunately, I still have some troubles understanding :(. Would be nice if you could help me one more time! I added the step that troubles me to the original question under "EDIT". And yes, your assumptions about z>0, and x∈(−∞,∞) are correct!

Comment: Thanks, again, now I totally get it! Next time will be easier :)